# query result alias

Tags: c#

Hi I've a query like this

select * from emplyees

result is

```
name    dept      status
emp1    Admin      y
emp2    admin      n
```

I'm going to bind it to gridview like mygridview.datasource = ds;

now here i want to display approve instead of y and disapprove instead of n

how can i write a query ?

thank you

Comment: Clear up the question please...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't state what database you are using. If you are using SQL Server, then you could write this as:

```
SELECT name, dept, CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Y' THEN 'Approve' ELSE 'Disapprove' END AS STATUS
FROM EMPLOYEES
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataGridView (Windows Forms) cell formatting mechanism to format value of a cell.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1cc356h%28VS.80%29.aspx)'s an example.

Comment: No i'm using web application.. any how i got the answer from the above query thank you